# Wsdl never updates

Tags: web-services, visual-studio-2010, asmx

No matter what I change in an asmx service in Visual Studio, the WSDL file stays always the same. Deleting methods, changing method signatures don't have any effect when I browse to service definition.

Comment: How are you looking at the "WSDL file"? By using "service.asmx?wsdl" ?

Comment: Yes. I browse to asmx file then click on service definition link which takes me to the service.asmx?wsdl.

Comment: Is your service part of a Web Application Project, or a Web Site (created via FIle->New Web Site)?

Comment: It runs inside an ASP.NET 3.5 web application project.

Answer (score 1):

I have had a simular problem.

When removing an enum and replacing it by a string, the enum wouldn't go away from the wsdl. No matter what I tried (clean, rebuild, clear browser cache, other browser), it kept returning the enum as a complex type within the WSDL.

The solution in my case was remove the local folders of the project via windows explorer, then perform a get latest from TFS. After this the problem was solved.

Of course this solution only aplies when using a sourcecontrol system.

Answer (score 0):

After changing your service, you must build it and ensure that the new version is running. One shortcut would be to build it (and make sure there are no errors), then right-click the .ASMX file and choose "View in Browser".

Also, although I'm sure you're aware of it, you should not be using ASMX web services for new development. Microsoft now considers ASMX to be a legacy technology. Use WCF instead.

Comment: I developed tens of web services before and this happens for the first time. Rebuilding and browsing to service definition changes nothing. This is legacy code, a project that has to be maintained so I have to work on it.

Comment: In my experience, when you change something, and it behaves as though it were not changed, then it's usually because you didn't change it. Make certain of whether the .dll file changes when you rebuild the service, etc. If necessary, delete the .dll file, and I bet it still works.

Comment: I copied the code to another machine and now the wsdl is updated. Got a reasonable explanation for this?

Comment: No, I don't. Just that somehow, you didn't actually make the change you thought you did, or you weren't actually testing the service you thought you were testing.

Comment: The same code compiled on a different machine generates the correct WSDL so I think I am not the cause here.

Comment: I didn't say that _you_ were the cause. I said that the change you made has not built and taken effect at the service URL you tested.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered this problem and have a solution.

**Cause:** When you create a new "Web Service" project in Visual Studio, it automatically adds a "Service1.asmx" file to your project.  You rename this file and change the class declaration inside of it, but Studio still thinks it's "Service1" wnd will only ever display the web service definition for "Service1".

**Solution:**

1. Delete all "bin" and "obj" folders in your project.
2. Copy the methods from your existing asmx file to notepad.
3. Remove the service from your project.
4. Add a new service to your project, with the name you want.
5. Paste the code from Notepad into the new service.
6. Rebuild All

Your asmx should now accurately reflect your web service and update normally on future builds.

Comment: I thought the ASMX file was the web service!  So what file is the web service because in the project I've inherited the ASMX file is in the web service project and then a mysterious `Reference.cs` file in the dependent project appears to be generated (or in this case, not generated) from that file.  Then there's the WSDL file (really an XML file) in the dependent project which also isn't actually included in the project (which makes me think that's supposed to be generated also).

Answer (score 0):

I had today the very same issue. It was caused by a GACed version of the assembly that contained the type definitions exposed by the web service. I had to remove the assembly from the Global Assembly Cache first, like:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\gacutil.exe" /u YourAssemblyNameWithouthDllExtebsion /f
```

Be sure to restart the web server hosting the web service to reload the new version of the assembly, for example, in case of IIS Express, you can kill the former process instance by PowerShell:

```
(Get-Process -Name iisexpress).Kill()
```

After that, the updated WSDL version was displayed as expected.